# How to send "update request" to rails api server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm new to Rails.

How should I send my update request to the rails server?

I understand that sending post request to /api/user create user.
Shuold I send post request to /api/user/id to update usr's name?

For example:
I want to update UserA's name.

My routes:

```
/api/user(.:format)
/api/current_users#update {:format=>:json}

// controller/User.rb
def update
  @current_user.attributes = user_params
  render json: { errors: @current_user.errors.full_messages }, status:
end
```

Below is my client code with Rxjs(Create request):

```
exhaustMap(({ payload }) => request({
  url: 'users',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    user: {
      email: payload.email,
      password: payload.password,
      device_token: device_token,
      sign_up_with: 'email_and_password',
    },
  },
```

So my question is, Can I update User by sending a POST request?
Should I do something else like POST update method???

Comment: Why do want to test it with CURL while their is  Postman? https://www.getpostman.com

Comment: I just want to know that How to update my User's name in my case.
In Restful solution.

Comment: The Postman app mentioned above makes it really simple to send HTTP requests (post, get...) to a route, including with configs such as a JSON payload etc.

Comment: thanks. However, I must use Rxjs to send post request to my Company's API server.
So, I need to usderstand how to update UserA's name by sending json with 'post'.
postman is a great. However I don't need postman.

Comment: Ideally update action is of request type `PUT` not `POST` if you have followed rails convention. Try changing request type.

Comment: Still if you wan to make `POST` request for update action, configure it in routes.rb file.

Comment: thank you, Asuik Salman.